# How to make the logo of a typo3 website dynamic by including typoscript in typo3 website

Tags: html

I have tried in setup.ts the following script:

```
      lib.logo = IMAGE
      lob.logo.file = fileadmin/template/img/logo.gif
```

and in html template(main.html)

```
      <div id="logo">    
      <f:cObject typoscriptpath="lib.logo"></f:cObject>    
      </div>
```

but didnt work

I am creating my own template in typo3 bootstrap package
please help me with the correct and complete solution..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.logo" />
```

worked for me